# mobilefirst logout redirect to new page

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using jquery mobile and I am using $.mobile.changePage( "#newpage"); option when the user authentication is done to move to next page. in the next page I have a logout button and when user clicks on that it has to logout and on success it has to come back to the login screen again.

```
WL.Client.logout('CustomAuthenticatorRealm',{onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp})
```

in this code onsuccess it is reloading the same url. i tried to change it like onSuccess: $.mobile.changePage( "#loginpage");

but it is not working. any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got it working ..

Instead making a page change I used onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp and for all the pages where I am using the load page function i have added changeHash: false so that the same url follows till the end . now it works fine as I expected

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that `#loginpage` bit, but that depends on your multiple pages implementation.

Anyway, try this instead as the `onSuccess` callback:
`$.mobile.changePage("#loginpage", { changeHash: false });`

Comment: WL.Client.logout('CustomAuthenticatorRealm',{onSuccess: $.mobile.changePage('#AuthBody', { changeHash: false });}) i tried this .. still no luck

Comment: Try `reloadPage: true` instead of `changeHash: false`.

Comment: it is coming back to login page. but if enter the login details and click on login button it is not working.I need to do a page refresh only then it is working

Comment: Try both reloadPage: true and WL.Client.reloadApp :)

Comment: Alright. Which environment is this? Please provide a project that can be debugged.

Comment: I am using Mobile first 7.0 and below is my project code in git https://github.com/gopi014/EPSML

Comment: Oh, that EPSML app... well you already have a question open where it's not possible to login, so I cannot test the logout. You also said your app works with a db that is not externally available.